# Unable to use workflow using osworkflow.jar in jira 8.18.0

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, osworkflow

We have developed a plugin in jira and We are using osworkflow to define our own custom workflow. Our plugin works within jira and when i try to initialize workflow,
We are getting this error in jira.log

> Caesium-1-3 ERROR ServiceRunner
> [c.a.jira.workflow.DefaultOSWorkflowConfigurator] Rejecting usage of
> unsafe workflow function/class:
> `com.service.workflow.condition.PermissionCondition`. You can enable
> usage of this class by adding
> `com.atlassian.jira.security.LegacyJiraTypeResolver.WARN_ONLY.enabled`
> dark feature flag to Jira. Do it only if you are sure its known and
> secure case. It will make Jira vulnerablefor potential attacks.

and below exception is printed

> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]
> com.opensymphony.workflow.WorkflowException: Could not load condition
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at
> com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.passesCondition(AbstractWorkflow.java:1045)
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at
> com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.passesConditions(AbstractWorkflow.java:1083)
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at
> com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.passesConditions(AbstractWorkflow.java:1107)
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at
> com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.canInitialize(AbstractWorkflow.java:862)
> [INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at
> com.opensymphony.workflow.AbstractWorkflow.initialize(AbstractWorkflow.java:598)

Our osworkflow.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE workflow PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//DTD OSWorkflow 2.8//EN" "http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/workflow_2_8.dtd">
<workflow>
    <initial-actions>
        <action id="1" name="Distribute">
            <meta name="addon.i18n.submit">com.form.distribute</meta>
            <meta name="addon.i18n.title">com.form.distribute</meta>
            <meta name="addon.description">com.form.distribute</meta>
            <meta name="addon.dist.status.id">1</meta>
            <meta name="addon.dist.user.status.id">1</meta>
            <restrict-to>
                <conditions>
                    <condition type="class">
                        <arg name="permission">HAS_DISTRIBUTION_PERMISSION</arg>
                        <arg name="class.name">com.service.workflow.condition.PermissionCondition</arg>
                    </condition>
                </conditions>
            </restrict-to>
            <results>
                <unconditional-result old-status="null" status="Open"
                    step="1">
                    <post-functions>
                        <function type="class">
                            <arg name="class.name">com.service.workflow.function.form.DistributeForm</arg>
                        </function>
                        <function type="class">
                            <arg name="class.name">com.service.workflow.function.form.AssignToReviewer</arg>
                        </function>
                        <function type="class">
                            <arg name="class.name">com.service.workflow.function.form.SendFormActionMail</arg>
                            <arg name="mail.action">1</arg>
                        </function>
                    </post-functions>
                </unconditional-result>
            </results>
        </action>
    </initial-actions>
    <common-actions>
    <action id="21" name="Distribution Close">
            <meta name="addon.i18n.submit">com.form.distribution.user.close</meta>
            <meta name="addon.i18n.title">com.form.distribution.user.close</meta>
            <meta name="addon.description">com.form.response.close.confirmation.message</meta>
            <meta name="addon.user.action">false</meta>         
            <results>
                <unconditional-result old-status="Open" status="close" step="-1">
                    <post-functions>
                        <function type="class">
                            <arg name="class.name">com.service.workflow.function.form.DistributionUserClose</arg>
                            <arg name="status">3</arg>
                        </function>
                        
                    </post-functions>
                </unconditional-result>
            </results>
        </action>
    </common-actions>
    <steps>
        <step id="1" name="Open">
            <actions>
                <common-action id="21" />
                <common-action id="22" />
                <common-action id="5" />
                <common-action id="2" />                
            </actions>
        </step>
        <step id="3" name="Re-Opened">
            <actions>
                <common-action id="5" />
                <common-action id="2" />
                <common-action id="21" />
                <common-action id="22" />               
            </actions>
        </step>
    </steps>
</workflow>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you use osworkflow outside Jira to generate a new workflow.xml file. And then import it into Jira? Seems odd not doing that inside Jira, but ok. I think I would start by exporting the XML of a working Jira workflow and then make sure that your generated workflow.xml looks like the one you know works

Comment: We are not exporting jira issue workflow. rather we are using osworkflow library used by jira to implement its workflows.
We have a developed a plugin in jira, which also have its own workflows like jira having its workflows for issues.
For this we also used osworkflow library and its APIs provided by jira. It was working till jira version 8.17.0 , however with jira 8.18.0 seems that somethings are changed and we started getting this exception